# Parse Cloud Code Queries do not return anything ever

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have some parse cloud code im running on my self hosted server but im running into an issue where queries are not doing anything. I can run commands through terminal and get data back but when I run a query.find.. nothing happens. For Example:

```
Parse.Cloud.job("getall", function(request, response) {
  var itemStatus = Parse.Object.extend('MovieStatus');
  var query = new Parse.Query(itemStatus);

  query.find({
    success: function(results) {
      console.log(results.length)
      response.success(results.length);
    },
    error: function(err) {
      response.error(err);
    },
    useMasterKey : true
  })
})
```

Nothing happens. No error no response. I have added console logs to make sure its at least getting called and it is, but for some reason nothing every returns from the server when I do `query.find`

I have tried all sorts of things to figure out what the issue is but this affects all of my cloud code so it has to be something in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an old syntax. Since version 3.0, Parse Server supports async/await style. Try this:

```js
Parse.Cloud.job("getall", async request => {
  ​const { log, message } = request;
  const ItemStatus = Parse.Object.extend('MovieStatus');
  const query = new Parse.Query(ItemStatus);
  const results = await query.find({ useMasterKey: true });
  log(response.length);
  message(response.length);
})
```

Not this is a job and not a cloud code function. You can invoke this job using Parse Dashboard and you should see the message in the job status section.